# How to get slice of string?

Tags: c, string, glib

Is there any function to get a substring in GLib?

Something like

```
gchar *getSlice(const gchar *text, gint startIndex);
```

Comment: did you try `gchar *slice = text + startIndex;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
 gchar *s = &text[start_index];
```

If you want a copy of the substring, do

```
 gchar *s = g_strdup(&text[start_index]);
```

Remember to free the string when you're done with it in the latter case.